# BIC vs Cross Validated MSE

Tags: regression, model-selection

While performing model selection, the subset selection method suggested that the model with 6-variable is the best fit for the data set based on BIC. Whereas the MSE obtained by performing Cross Validation on the same data set suggests that the model with 11-variable give the best accuracy. Which one would perform well on new data?

In case you want have a clear picture of what I asked or need the data set, you can check out the Lab Exercise 6.5 of the book ['Introduction to Statistical Learning in R'](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither of the methods you describe are methods for finding a model that fits best. BIC is a method for choosing a model with the best tradeoff between fit and complexity, and cross-validation is a method for choosing a model with the best out-of-sample predictive accuracy. It doesn't make sense to ask which method is better because they have different goals, and I'm not sure what you mean by "reliable", anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have edited the question and the content and defined the objective.

Comment: @melwin_jose If by "perform well" you mean predict the dependent variable accurately, the second of your two methods is better, because that's the sort of question it's supposed to help you answer. By contrast, maximizing out-of-sample predictive accuracy is not a goal of BIC.

Comment: yes, thats what i meant by by "performing well". My apologizes for using the wrong terminologies, I am very new to the field of data science. As BIC is dependent on RSS and number of variable, shouldn't the model suggested by it perform well, as it tries to reduce the training MSE along with the model complexity and thus avoid over-fitting. On the other hand, CV'ed MSE just takes in to account RSS and suggests the model with lowest MSE but doesn't avoid over-fitting due to variables. Sorry again if i  misunderstood what BIC and CV'ed MSE are.

Comment: @melwin_jose The important difference here is that BIC counters overfitting with an explicit rule for penalizing model complexity, whereas CV directly estimates out-of-sample predictive accuracy, which already incorporates any harm to predictive accuracy due to overfitting. So if predictive accuracy is what you want, you should go with CV. There's no guarantee that the BIC complexity penalty will exactly offset the effect of overfitting on predictive accuracy; it can overcompensate or undercompensate.

Comment: @melwin_jose "Perform well" isn't the wrong term, by the way—it's just vague, because there are many different notions of a model's performance.